# Where do I go after finishing the fourth dungeon (The Forest Temple)?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I have just cleared the Forest Temple in Ocarina of Time.

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple choices after clearing the Forest Temple, but most people prefer doing the Fire Temple next.  Go to the Goron Village and ask around and I'm sure you'll make some headway.

Comment: The Fire Temple is the expected path, at any rate.

Comment: I did the fire temple first.  It was a bit of a stretch, not having arrows for the boss...